# Is it acceptable to write several small papers that contribute to a larger paper?

Tags: arxiv, self-promotion, self-citation

To keep this brief, I have two new math ideas that are supporting a larger work. I want to write two small papers detailing these math ideas (plus some other details I figured out about them), publish them to arXiv, and then cite them in the larger work. The smaller papers do not have enough substance for a journal or conference.

I want to do this because I want to provide details for the interested reader which are irrelevant to the larger work.

I am still new to this, so I ask: Is this acceptable? This feels like it might be unethical self promotion / self citation.

Comment: ArXiv preprints are not considered as publication, so no need to worry about the last bit. But for self-completeness, I'd say it 's a better idea to add the two _papers_ as appendices to the larger paper.

Comment: if they don't have enough substance for a conference contribution, putting them into the supplementary material/appendix of the larger work is imho the more reasonable/efficient decision for yourself AND the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state it, you are probably going to be fine, however, you have a bit of risk. The first is that if the ArXiv papers aren't really "publications", then citing them doesn't really add much to your CV other than a bit of noise.

The second risk is that a publisher has to agree that your "combined" work is still sufficiently novel to want to actually publish it and that is up to them and not a question that can be answered here. If all the novelty is already "out there" you might have a problem. This is less of an issue in math, of course, which has a preprint culture currently.

An alternative strategy, that you can use or not, would be to write a good paper with the important results and then put the supplementary material somewhere that it could be found.

So, ask yourself whether the combined paper is more than the sum of its parts for your reputation. It might be, or not, depending on the results.

Answer (score 2):

Why not combine the extra stuff into one document "additional results on X"?

Otherwise no one really cares. But you might want to label it as a "report" or "supplement" so it won't be mistaken for a sad paper that failed to get published. There are certainly some highly-cited unpublished reports on ArXiv.

And ArXiv can count as publication with some journals, so you have to take a little care if you build on the results later and want to publish the material.

It can be informative to put on your CV, for some uses. It tells people what you've been working on. Plus if someone likes your research and finds their way to your CV, they will be led to your reports too. I'd suggest a section tiled "Reports" or "Unpublished preprints" or something. And for formal situations where you want to avoid looking like you're padding the CV, just leave that section out.